# Elasticserach forcemerge and disc space problem

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, server, logstash, diskspace

I'm new to Elasticsearch, so don’t blame me much.
The situation is this, the server has almost run out of logging space, about 400 MB remains. I had to delete the old logs of two years ago, but as it turned out, it simply marks them deleted, but in fact, deletes them in the background during auto-merge. The index that I was trying to clean up is actively using for write logs to it, but in order to free up disk space, I decided to run a `POST /logging/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true` . Through the `GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*forcemerge`, I see that the task is running, but for 2 hours nothing has been happening. The place is not vacated and there is a feeling that it was not worth doing a force merge and listening to all the reviews on forums and sites about this procedure.

The questions themselves.

1. Is there any way I can find out how long force merge will last?
2. I turned off the servers that write to this index, as I understand it, is it not worth writing to the index during force merge?
3. Since I used the parameter only_expunge_deletes=true to merge only segments with deleted documents, will this affect the search by index?
4. What is the best practice that would not arise in such situations?

Comment: a little update. force merge ended, I don't obtained any additional space and now I get an error when trying to make a search in the index


Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[],"caused_by":{"type":"no_shard_available_action_exception","reason":null,"index_uuid":"iHJV2S92RHqVcru2IUYpDQ","shard":"4","index":"logging"}},"status":503}

Comment: response from /logging/_segments?pretty now like this

{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "indices" : { }
}

before i see info about shards and segments and index

Comment: What is the size of your index? How many documents does it have? Force merge can takes a really long time and there is no way to track the progress. If you are storing time based events like logs, it is better to use time based index, instead of having a index named `logging`, you would having many index named `logging-2020-02-02` for example, then when you need to delete old logs, you can delete the entire index and the space is freed at the same moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way I can find out how long force merge will last?

No, sorry, a force merge doesn't report any information about its progress.

> 2. I turned off the servers that write to this index, as I understand it, is it not worth writing to the index during force merge?

A force merge is [generally only useful when you will never again write to an index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html). There's no reason to stop writing to an index just for the duration of the merge, but conversely if you wish to continue writing to an index then it's not recommended to force-merge it at all.

> 3. Since I used the parameter only_expunge_deletes=true to merge only segments with deleted documents, will this affect the search by index?

Merging is often beneficial for searches, which is why Elasticsearch (really Lucene) does it in the background. However, force-merging can disrupt the usual automatic merge process in future, which is why it's recommended not to do it on indices that will see future writes.

> 4. What is the best practice that would not arise in such situations?

I think a good practice that you are missing, given that you are indexing logs, is to use *time-based indices*: every so often (e.g. monthly) start a new index whose name contains the date (e.g. month and year). Elasticsearch lets you search across multiple indices at once (maybe using a wildcard or an [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)). Then you can manage the lifecycle of these indices individually (there's even a [feature for automatic index lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html)) which includes deleting older indices when they reach a suitable age. Deleting a subset of the documents in an index is expensive and doesn't necessarily save space, but deleting an entire index is cheap and frees up space immediately.